# How to use google analytics content group data in a real time

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a website that enabled google analytics content grouping by tracking code.

For channel one ==> ga('set', 'contentGroup1', 'Channel1'); 
For channel two ==> ga('set', 'contentGroup1', 'Channel2');

Can I use it like above so later I can check what data for Channel1 and Channel2

Also I want to check is it possible to use content grouping data in the real time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of nomenclature, content groupings have nothing to do with "Channels" as the word is usually used in Analytics. "Channel" mostly refers to the marketing channel, i.e. the way you have acquired a visit by a user. Channel is a session based metric that does not change during a session (because changing the channel will by definition start a new session). You can see the information that defines the channel (i.e. source, medium, campaign) in the realtime view (but not the channel itself).

On the other hand it might be that you are simply using the english word "channel" to separate your content into groups.

Content groups are a hit based metric, meaning this does not pertain to visits or user but to individual pageviews. So yes of course, you can see data per content group - you'd have to go to the behavior reports in the menu; if you look at the "All pages" data table there is a small navigation above the table where you can select your content groups as primary dimension. This will show you aggregated hit based metrics (pageviews, entrances, bounces etc) per content group.

You cannot use this in realtime view.